# Delete Bulk button does not use custom dataProvider

Tags: react-admin

The delete bulk action is by default inserted in React Admin List.
But when you try to delete an item it doesn't trigger the dataProvider.
I want to delete the item permanently and trigger the DELETE crud in the dataProvider. 
Anyone any ideas on how to do this?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOWJy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does trigger the data provider, what it trigger is DELETE_MANY (type) 
so your custom data provider file inside the switch statement check for DELETE_MANY type and then you can write your logic there. I'm actually having the same issue 
I have a end point in my server for deleting the object but  delete bulk button was triggering a different endpoint so I needed to reroute the request.

here is some of my logic if it works for you (custom dataprovider.js )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVdbz.png)

hope that helps!